# routing with non rest actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

im having some trouble creating a route for my non restfull action in my controller, here is my code:

controller:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController

  def toggle_store
    @store=Store.find(params[:store])
    if @store.available==true
      @store.update_attribute(:available, false)
    else
      @store.update_attribute(:available, true)
    end
    redirect_to @store
  end

end
```

routes:

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :stores do
      member do
        post :toggle_store
      end
    end
  end
```

but when i use the path in a link i get this url: http://example.com/groups/1/stores/toggle_store.2

and i need something like this:
http://example.com/groups/1/stores/2/toggle_store

any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

rake routes:

```
toggle_store_group_store POST   /groups/:group_id/stores/:id/toggle_store(.:format) stores#toggle_store
```

Link:

```
<%=link_to "toggle", toggle_store_group_stores_path(@group,store), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: How are you creating your path? Please also copy a part of output of `rake routes`.

Comment: done, i added the rake routes and how i link it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fixed it like this:

routes.rb:

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :stores do
      post :toggle_store      
    end
  end
```

controller:

```
  def toggle_store
    authorize! :toggle, :store
    @store=Store.find(params[:store_id])
    if @store.available==true
      @store.update_attribute(:available, false)
    else
      @store.update_attribute(:available, true)
    end
    redirect_to @group
  end
```

link:

```
<%=link_to "to", toggle_store_group_store_path(@group,store), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: Okay, glad you solved it, but no idea what was your problem, since on my machine everything worked fine. Just a note: you should not be using `:method => :post` with a `link_to` method, since when the user opens this link in a new tab/window, the method attribute gets lost and the link is sent as a get request. Consider using `button_to` or something else.

Comment: BTW, there is a toggle! method to toggle and store attributes: @store.toggle!(:available) . At least you should get rid of the if with something like: @store.update_attribute(:available, !@store.available)